# datatables / jquery / session variable / login form

Tags: datatables

Scenario:

1) login.php verifies the username and password and sets a session with the user id

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

2) datatables / jquery calls an action.php file to fill the table with data

```
"ajax":{
      url:"action.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{action:'listTable'},
      dataType:"json"
    },
```

3) the action.php file calls the function listTable()

```
include('table.php');
$table = new table();
$table->listTable();
```

4) the listTable function (table.php) returns the whole data which is landing in the datatable

```
$output = array(
      "draw"        =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
      "recordsTotal"    =>  $numRows,
      "recordsFiltered"   =>  $numRows,
      "data"          =>  $tableData
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
```

5) the data was selected with a sql command and was put into the tableData variable

Everything works fine in that case.

Ideas:

I wanted to acccess the session variable within the sql select command. This is not possible, because of the jquery / action.php api. Those are complete different files and have no access to that session. It is possible to set the user id within a hidden formular field, but this is not secure and easy to manipulate. A cookie file is also user editable. Furthermore Javascript cannot read server side session variables.

Question:

How can i use / access that php session variable in that scenario?

Update:

Thats not working too :/

overview.php

```
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];
```

data.js

```
"ajax":{
      url:"action.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{userID:userID, action:'listTable'},
      dataType:"json"
    },
```

table.php

```
$userID = $_POST["userID"];
```

Comment: https://webdamn.com/datatables-add-edit-delete-with-ajax-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand here the problem, because of `$_SESSION` variable is available across the php files even if an ajax calls the php file. Until you call the AJAX call from the same browser and the ajax call includes the cookies (one of the cookie will be the session ID) then you will be able to reach your user ID in the SQL query on the PHP side, without passing to javascript/jquery your user's ID.
As you wrote in login.php:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

In your table.php where the SQL command is living:

```
echo isset($_SESSION['id']) ? "I'm existing!" : "I'm NOT existing!";
```

It will print "I'm existing!" if the user logged in and "I'm NOT existing!" if the user didn't log in. All the $_SESSION variables are available across the php files until the server gets the SESSION ID from the browser (which is a cookie). Cookies are automatically sent if you calling the same domain.

Comment: I have tried to access the session variable already but it was not working. Also echo commands will not work, because i am not including the table.php file directly.

Comment: Amm this will be a stupid question, but do you called `session_start()` before you set the value and before you tried to read the value? (only once needs to be called per request. i.e. at the beginning of the file). Echo will work whatever you doing. The wrong case it will mess up your response, like `var_dump()` also does it.

Comment: `session_start();
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];
//echo isset($_SESSION['id']) ? "I'm existing!" : "I'm NOT existing!";
//var_dump($userID);
//echo "test";`

The var_dump and the two echo commands lead to the following error: DataTables warning: table id=listTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Yes, and if you view the network log of your browser, you will see the message printed by those commands, and then following the JSON message. That's why you get an invalid JSON response. Because DataTables expects only JSON. But you can still debug by using the methods, and viewing your browsers network tab (ignoring the error message), where you can explicitly see the response from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solved it by implementing the login process in the table.php class. The other seperate login file hasn't worked, because i couldn't access the session.